# Animate UIView Removed From Superview in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, uikit

I have a sliding UIViewController presented on top of the main view controller, this sliding vc displays some additional info and can be dragged up to make it bigger, the issue is that when the VC is dismissed, there is no animation. This is what I've tried and it just disappears. How can I animate removing it from the superview?

```
                        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, delay: 1, options: .curveEaseInOut) {
                            self.view.alpha = 0
                        } completion: { _ in
                            self.view.removeFromSuperview()
                            self.removeFromParent()
                        }
```

Comment: Best way to do is using `UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning` api

reference: https://github.com/canopas/DraggableViewController

Comment: @SPatel I already have the ViewController implemented, I just want an animation on dismiss rather than it disappearing

Comment: @tHatpart UIViewAnimate will not work , you need to look at SPatel comment